# Locking a Button After Press for a period of time

Tags: android, button, timer

Here is the scenario:

User opens app, they press a button and some activity launches.  After the button is pressed and the activity is executed, I want to disable the button until the week starts over. Even if they close the app and come back, it should still be disabled unless it has reset.

For example, if they press the button on Monday, they should not be able to do it again until Sunday at 12:00 AM.

No matter what day they initially press the button, they should not be able to press again until the week starts over.

What would be the simplest way to do this in android?  Should I have the program store the date and time they initially press, and then calculate the time until reset every time they open the app?

Comment: Antifeature! This is going to be really annoying if the user pushes a button by accident, now they can't use that button for a week.

Comment: Well you just have to add a confirmation window to avoid this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could think of for you would be to put the dates in the database of your app. So that when the user clicks the button, you create a Date object, put it in the format you want and create another one + 7 days in the same format. You put the 2nd date in the database and every time you launch the activity with the button, you check the database and compare the date of the day with the one in the database. This way, no calculation done after retrieving the value from the DB, just comparison. You finally just have to set up the images of the button and its clickable states to match the results of the test.

Comment: I haven't worked much with databases...can you link to an example or tutorial that might help out?

Comment: I also don't want it to be 7 days, it should always reset on Sunday.  So I need to determine the time between the date it is pressed and Sunday at 12:00 AM

Comment: Well, you requirements might make the work a bit more complicated but that does not change a lot the reasonning... In your case, you just want to grab the closest sunday after the press, store its date in the DB and then compare with the date every time the activity is opened

Comment: you can find loads of information about dates and days in java on the web. For instance, this one : http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0403.html

Comment: Thanks for the date link, that helped out getting the current day. How would I get the closest sunday to store in the db for comparison upon app launch?

Comment: You can use a shared preference for this just fine. No reason to use a database for 1 value.